# Responsive Design Viewport issue

Tags: responsive-design

**Consider the following code using Bootstrap 3:**

```
<div class = "col-xs-7 col-lg-2">
```

In an sm viewport the div will be _____ columns wide.

How do I find the number of columns? Does some of them have default values

Answer (score 0):

If a viewport setting is not defined, it will inherit from the next smaller viewport or use the default (12).

In this example the "sm" viewport is not defined, but the smaller "xs" is so its value will be used.  Therefore, the answer is 7.